# Getting Null for the Button while using findViewById in Android

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-button

I have created a button in XML file and while i am trying to access the button through findViewById, i am getting NullPointer Exception.

The Id is for the button is generated in R.java file. But still i couldn't able to get through findViewById method.

Main.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<com.example.calendar_module.CalendarView  android:id="@+id/calendar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/NextMonth"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Next"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // 1) start calendar view
           //       startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK).setDataAndType(null, CalendarActivity.MIME_TYPE), 100);
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setDataAndType(null, CalendarActivity.MIME_TYPE));
    final CalendarView calenderView = new CalendarView(this);

  //         Calendar calendarView = Calendar.getInstance();
 //
 //      Uri uriCalendar = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/time/" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
 //         Intent intentCalendar = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,uriCalendar);
 //
 //         //Use the native calendar app to view the date
 //         startActivity(intentCalendar);

    Button NextMonth = (Button) findViewById(R.id.NextMonth);

    System.out.println("NextMonth Id "+NextMonth);

    NextMonth.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            calenderView.nextMonth();

        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

  // 2) implement your own onActivityResult method to handle returned date

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(resultCode==RESULT_OK) {
        int year = data.getIntExtra("year", 0);   // get number of year
        int month = data.getIntExtra("month", 0); // get number of month 0..11
        int day = data.getIntExtra("day", 0);     // get number of day 0..31

        // format date and display on screen
        final Calendar dat = Calendar.getInstance();
        dat.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        dat.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
        dat.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);

        // show result
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MMM dd");
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, format.format(dat.getTime()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}

}
```

Comment: check whether button is in `activity_main.xml` or in some other xml

Comment: please post the `activity_main.xml`

Comment: you posted main.xml, but setContentView() to activity_main.xml. that is your problem

Comment: @venkat, post your error here

Comment: I am just having the Hello World in the Activity_main.xml. Nothing much in that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to read a few more tutorials if you don't fully grasp the concept of layouts and the xml format.

basically, you just need to change this

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

to this

```
setContentView(R.layout.Main);
```

where `Main` is the actual name of your xml file with the layout you want to use

Answer (score -1):

@venkat,

1. you can clean the project, delete the gen folder and rebuild the app. This should fix the issue.
2. To get the id use `System.out.println("NextMonth Id "+NextMonth.getId());`